# When using the zodiac modulue my transaction simulation works but, when i try executing my transaction on tally it reverts the transaction

Tags: solidity, metamask, gnosis-safe, defi, multisignature

i keep trying to use the zodiac govener module on my gnosis safe but no transaction is working at all, ive followed the youtube guide and firstly when i use the transaction encoder i get this error for transfering a ERC20 token from my safe to a wallet "Transaction reverted ERC20: transfer from the zero address"

i have screen shots that i provided below, this is all on goerli test net also.

these are the contracts for the ERC20 token : 0x07f6F5a351f5F4eDF6F262C513325bdC3651d8ff
SAFE: 0x2CD988f38Bbcc59E91E4BeB263362224AEf38F27

I then tried to simulate the transaction just using my wallet as the owner of the SAFE, i then took that signature of the transfer and put it as a proposal.

On the transaction simulation it says that its running correctly but then when i press execute on the function it doesnt work it says the execution needs reverting. (screenshot below).

Also tried transfering just Goerli ETH and the run-simulation said it will work but when i press execute i still keep getting the transaction reverted error, i don't know what is wrong with this and i need some help please

I’ve tried on mainnet now the simulation said it should work
But when I press execute it just reverts. Essentially the transaction could run well in simulation but when i press execute once the proposal passes the transaction reverts.
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]